# Fix the ordering of overlaid geom_bar and position_identity() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

There are a few questions asking about ordering of **stacked** `geom_bar()` graphs. I however have the issue that I need to overlay the bar graphs, but for some reason the ordering is making it so that the bottom layers are getting hidden by the top-most one. Consider this example:

```
df_example = data.frame(Month = rep(c(1:8),2),
                    Type = c(rep("Email",8),rep("SMS",8)),
                    Notifications = c(4,7,9,11,13,17,19,20,2,4,4,3,3,3,4,4))
```

I then plot using ggplot2 and `geom_bar()`

```
ggplot(data=df_example,aes(x=Type, y=Notifications, fill=Type, color=Type))+
geom_bar(stat="identity",position ="identity", color= "black",alpha=0.5)+
coord_flip()
```

And get this:

[image]

The problem is that the overlaying is "hiding" the lower layers. I ideally want each segment well defined, and demarcated with the black outline. I really can't get this and it's bugging me. I am trying to re-create something like this:

[image]

Note, this was done in paint, so the numbers won't line up - but the visual idea is there.

Any help with this ggplot issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fair enough, I could do that - but I want the colors to be a solid color. I could theoretically put `alpha = 0` and then edit on a different program. But that just seems cumbersome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: add a row number, grouping by type, then use that to fill in each colour and stack the bars. You can then edit the colours and remove the legend.

```r
df %>% group_by(Type) %>% mutate(r=factor(seq(1,n()))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Type, y=Notifications))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=r),stat="identity",position = 'stack', color= "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(rep('lightblue',8))) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Your overlay idea won't work perfectly, since you have duplicate values for Notification. See below -- arranging the data first by Notification then plotting achieves the solid colour overlay, but hides the fact that there are duplicates (whereas the stacked bar shows this).

```r
df %>% arrange(Type,-Notifications) %>% 
  ggplot(.,aes(x=Type, y=Notifications))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill='Type'),stat="identity",position ="identity", color= "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(rep('lightblue',16)))
```

[image]

Comment: So, unfortunately this only works because you have `position = 'stack'`. Where as I need to use `position = "identity"`. The  `position = 'stack'` gives an additive amount for notifications. This would be incorrect as it makes it look like 100 notifications were received via Email after 8 months.

Comment: I don't think your overlay idea is the more appropriate, since it hides some of the data (ie, the duplicate Notification values). See the update.

Comment: That's okay. I don't mind if there is some overlap. Your update works. Was it really just adding in an `arrange` that made the difference :/. But yeah, I am happy to accept as answer

Comment: Yeah, adding the `arrange` call was all it took. Thanks.